# When testing Visual Studio 2013 Microsoft Edge appears and asks for id and password

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, microsoft-edge

I have a VS2013 website developed in VB with Windows 10.  I have tested it for years but now after migrating to Windows 10 when I go into debug mode, Edge pops up and asks for a user id and password. I have no user id or password that it accepts and I don't want that to happen anyway since it doesn't happen in production.

How can I get rid of the login requirement?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! A screenshot may help. If you edit the question, you can click the image tool and upload it. If you don't already have a screenshot tool I recommend IrfanView.

Comment: @BobStein-VisiBone Why not just use Windows' *Snipping Tool*? You're correct though, a screenshot here would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your site has windows auth switched on. Ordinarily IE would negotiate for you and sign you in seamlessly. Edge doesn't seem to handle NTLM in the same way. To get your previous experience you could just switch the debug browser to IE11. This also has the benefit of enabling JS debugging which also currently breaks with Edge as VS2013. I'm sure these issues with Edge and VS will be fixed shortly.

Comment: still not fixed out of the box with VS 2015